# MapServer, Mapcache and WMS

Tags: wms, mapserver, mapcache

I try to use MapServer 7.4 with MapCache 1.6.1 on a Suse SLES
15-system.
MapServer is delivering a WMS very well.
I installed MapCache successfully (I think).
In my mapcache.xml I have set:

```
<source name="kanaldaten" type="wms">
<getmap>
<params>
<FORMAT>image/jpeg</FORMAT>
<LAYERS>schaechte</LAYERS>
</params>
</getmap>
<http>
<url>http://blablabla/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/blablabla/wms.map</url>
</http>
</source>

   <tileset name="kachelnkanal">
      <source>kanaldaten</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid>WGS84</grid>
      <format>PNG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>3600</expires>
   </tileset>
```

If I use the WMS-demo application:

http://blablabla/mapcache/demo/wms everything works fine.
A couple of tiles are produced on the server.

But: If I use my WMS e.g. in QuantumGIS or at a simple
...GetMap-Request in an URL
no tiles at all are produced on the server??

Am I right that the tile-producing only works, if the mapclient has
specific entries?

Answer (score 1):

Allright, forget that question.

¶

The answer is:

Not the WMS-URL should be opened in the client but the url to the mapcache-software:

¶

e.g.:

¶

`var wmsSource = new ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://blabla/mapcache/?',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'kachelnkanal'},
    serverType: 'mapserver',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });`

var wmsLayer = new ImageLayer({
    source: wmsSource
  });